# get very nested elements (RSelenium), but how?

Tags: r, rselenium

[image: firefox-inspector]

I want automate my e-mail with RSelenium, but there is a very nested element (see at the marked position) which costs me hours. This doesn't work:

```
es1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="id6"]')
```

then i try this (onion strategy):

```
es1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="app-contents-wrapper"]/atl-app-stack/atl-app-iframe[3]')$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="thirdPartyFrame_home"]')$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html')$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body')
```

So far everyone is fine! But if i tail the next:

```
es1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="app-contents-wrapper"]/atl-app-stack/atl-app-iframe[3]')$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="thirdPartyFrame_home"]')$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html')$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body')$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="id56"]')
```

R produced this error message (and also if I do id6 directly):

```
Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="id56"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64)

Fehler:      Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?